# Python - Click Enter to Repeat - How?

Tags: python

I have this code:

```
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4)   
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.122 Safari/537.36')]
br.open("http://de.fakenamegenerator.com/gen-male-gr-gr.php")

soup = BeautifulSoup(br.response())
address = soup.find('div', attrs={"class": "address"})
tel = soup.find('span', attrs={"class": "value"})

print address.h3.text.strip()
print address.find('div', attrs={'class': 'adr'}).text.strip()
print tel.text.strip()

closeInput = raw_input("Drueck Enter = Close")
print "Closing..."
```

Now my question is, what is the command if I want to repeat it with clicking something?
Like "Click F1 to repeat" or something...

Thanks!

Comment: use while or if statements ??

Comment: What's your question? How to repeat your piece of code, or how to capture key presses?

Answer (score -2):

There's probably a better way to do this but here's how I would do it...

```
repeat = True
while repeat == True
br = mechanize.Browser()
br.addheaders = [('User-agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_4)   
AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.122 Safari/537.36')]
br.open("http://de.fakenamegenerator.com/gen-male-gr-gr.php")

soup = BeautifulSoup(br.response())
address = soup.find('div', attrs={"class": "address"})
tel = soup.find('span', attrs={"class": "value"})

print address.h3.text.strip()
print address.find('div', attrs={'class': 'adr'}).text.strip()
print tel.text.strip()

closeInput = raw_input("Drueck Enter = Close")
print "Closing..."

print("type repeat if you want this code to repeat")
repeat = raw_input()
```

This means, if they type repeat, it will repeat and if not(or if they type something else), it won't.